# D3 .on sends 3 arguments to a callback function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I read in the [D3 docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on):

> The specified listener is invoked in the same manner as other operator functions, being passed the current datum d and index i, with the this context as the current DOM element.

But when I run it like this:

```
d3.select('.bar')
  .on('click', _toggleBar)
```

Then I see 3 arguments being passed to the `_toggleBar` function:

```
function _toggleBar() {
    console.log('arguments.length: ' + arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

[image: 3 arguments passed to callback]

Where there is a datum object, index and third argument which is always zero.

Why does it happen and what's this third argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [d3.js source for on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/on.js) (as per discussion in the comments below):

```
d3_selectionPrototype.on = function(...) {
    ...
    return this.each(d3_selection_on(...);
}
```

The parameters being passed through are the ones being passed to `selection.each`. Which, based on [that source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/each.js), takes 3 params:

```
return d3_selection_each(this, function(node, i, j) {...
```

Which as @CoolBlue correctly identifies is the group index and is shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysywp8ed/2/).

Comment: I'm not sure about that @Tony... if you trace the code you will find that `onAdd` is the function passed back to  `return this.each(d3_selection_on(type, listener, capture));` in `d3_selectionPrototype.on`. That means that the arguments passed to the listener (via `wrap`, which in this case is `d3_selection_onListener`) are the ones passed by `selection.each` which is actually `d`, `i` and `j`. So I think the third argument is `j` (the "group" index) , not `capture`. And this is most often zero since most selections are a single group.

Comment: Just to clarify, `d3_selectionPrototype.on` ends up returning  `this.each(onAdd)`

Comment: @CoolBlue Well, I attempted to create an example that would have multiple group indexes but I'm not sure it's correct. I did show that it's not the `capture` variable though, so I will update my answer. Here's my test [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysywp8ed/). Feedback appreciated.

Comment: I've tried a handful of different select combinations and couldn't get it to change. But, based on the source I have to agree with your assessment, @CoolBlue.

Comment: check out [this fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CoolBlue/ysywp8ed/1/) ;)